# Datatable fnRowCallback function for calling new function

Tags: jquery, callback, datatables

i am using fnRowCallback function for calling new function.

when i given like dis.

```
 "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        var me = "addTab2('coust:plans','coustplans.php')";     
        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="#" data= "' + aData[1] +'plans.php" title="' + aData[1] +'plans" class="addnew" onclick="' + me + '">' +
                aData[1] + '</a>')
```

it's working fine

When i given

```
var me = "addTab2('' + aData[1] +':plans','' + aData[1] +'plans.php')";
```

it's not working. i want i display dat coustname through dynamic.

if once dis function i given in inline

`$('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="#" title="' + aData[1] +'" onclick="addTab2('' + aData[1] +':plans','' + aData[1] +'plans.php')">' +
                    aData[1] + '</a>');`
 it's showing syntax error.

so how can i help out it.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error 'cause you have 2 little errors with the Single quotes:

```
$('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="#" title="' + aData[1] +'" onclick="addTab2('' + aData[1] +':plans','' + aData[1] +'plans.php')">' + aData[1] + '</a>');
```

I tried this and it works for me:

```
$("#test").html('<a href="#" title="' + aData[1] +'" onclick="addTab2(' + aData[1] + ':plans,' + aData[1] +'plans.php)">' + aData[1] + '</a>');
```

(#test is a div for tests i don't create a table)

It's a Single quotes problem. I recommend you to use the developers tools from Chrome and some text editor like Sublime 2.

Comment: yes it's coming fine. i want give function like dis "addTab2('coustplans','coustplans.php')" ; i want give single (') dis one must and should for this function. otherwise it's not working for me.

Comment: @marvan ahhh now i understand, so it's so easy, only scape the character, like this `'<a href="#" title="' + aData[1] +'" onclick="addTab2(\'' + aData[1] + 'plans\',\'' + aData[1] +'plans.php\')">' + aData[1] + '</a>'` you know you can escape special characters with **\** i tried this and work (:

Comment: @marvan you are welcome (: ! i will appreciate if you mark this answer  as the solution :)